# In iOS 7 Mobile Safari's bookmarks, how did Apple make the segmented control persist when the navigation controller pushes?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

It seems like it's pushing to a new view controller, but that segmented control doesn't move. I don't think it's a table header or a custom UIBarButtonItem in the nav bar. How  do they do it?

[image: Spooky segmented control]

Comment: To me it looks like they added the segmented control directly to the navigation bar. If that's the case there might not be a solution for non-Apple apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass your navigation controller and add custom subview.